# How to customize location manager prompt?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I am working on an app. In this app I want to customize location manager prompt alert. This prompt ask "XXX" would like to use your current location.

I have attached a screen shot regarding this. 
[image]

Now what I want I want to show customized alert. That will not be like an alert actually. It will simply ask to use your current location or city/state/zip.

In this way when user clicks on use current location then it will be like default location manager prompt. Otherwise other page will be opened and User can enter formalities.

Please guide me in this.

Thanks,

Cp

Comment: If you are planning to show above UI as an image, you can try this http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/

Answer (score 0):

In Past, You have to use `NSLocationUsageDescription` in your info.plist file. After iOS 8, you have to use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

**NOTE: From iOS 8 onwards, you should add a proper description for your location usage. Otherwise your app will get rejected by App Store app reviewer.**

Once you added the description in the info.plist. It will show the permission alert view like below.

[image]

[image]